# How can I mount a 2" mast to the side of a utility pole?

Tags: hardware, mounting

I need to mount a 2" diameter mast to the side of a utility/telephone pole and am having trouble locating a mounting solution/hardware that will work.

My big problem is that I'm not sure what the name of such hardware is and that is making it tough to find using Google. Searching for "pole mount" just returns hits about mounting the pole itself, not mounting TO a pole. I've thought about using some kind of clamps around both poles, but ideally I'd like something that provides a little bit of offset between the poles. Maybe there is come kind of adapter hardware that would allow for a flush mount against a pole?

Can anyone provide some advice for the name of the hardware you'd use for this, or just general advice on how to securely mount a mast to the side of a telephone pole with a bit of an offset and flushly?

Comment: Um ... I don't know about in your area, but in mine, it's illegal to attach things to utility poles.  (although, typically, it's people putting campaign / yard sale / we buy junk cars / make money from home / etc signs up on them)

Comment: It is my pole. I installed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try searching for "utility pole standoff bracket" and you'll find things like [this Garvin bracket](http://www.garvinindustries.com/Hanging-and-Support/Service-Entrance/Service-Drop-Brackets-and-Clamps/SOB-1). Also check if the [Band-It Company](http://www.band-it-idex.com/en/index.html) has something you can use.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the size of the pole, you might be able to use a chimney mount, which is straps that go around a solid object, or possibly a wall mount type if you can screw into the pole. [ChannelMaster](http://www.channelmaster.com/TV_Antenna_Mounts_s/28.htm) sells a variety of mounts, but you can also find some at your friendly local Radio Shack, though the 2" requirement might be a problem, I think most of the antenna-type mounts will top out at 1.5".

Comment: I can get by with a 1.5" pole if I need to.

Answer (score 1):

I snagged a piece of girder used as a highway guard rail.  Bolted one edge to the pole with two, 1 inch threaded rods through the pole, and then drilled muffler clamps into the wide flat side.

Heavy duty, and rugged as heck.  Works great.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the weight of what you are mounting on the pipe, you may be able to use something like this:  [Channel Master Universal Mount for Small TV Antenna](http://www.solidsignal.com/pview.asp?mc=03&p=CM3009&d=Channel-Master-CM3009-Universal-Mount-Roof-or-Wall-for-Small-TV-Antenna-%28CM3009%29&c=Mounting%20Supplies&sku=).   I have one mounted to the wood siding on the side of our house with lag screws; you could probably do the same on a utility pole.

Comment: That doesn't seem like it would sit flush against a round pole.

Comment: You might need shims under the edges, or it may be tight enough without, since it's relatively narrow.   If you own the pole, you could also potentially chisel a small flat spot for it.   It looks like the Garvin bracket in matsukaze's answer would work better, though.